# How to save an uploaded image in an admin form?

Tags: 7, files

I wrote the following module to upload a background image. My problem is, that my submit function is not called, though the pic is uploaded and showed in the block until the next cleanup is coming.The managed file table shows status 0...what should be 1 as far as i know.

Here is the Code of my Module: Whats the mistake?

```
function backgroundimage_block_info() {
    // This example comes from node.module.
    $blocks['backgroundimage'] = array(
        'info' => t('Background Image'),
    );


    return $blocks;
}
function backgroundimage_block_view($delta = '') {
    $fid_now=variable_get('backgroundimage');
    dpm($fid_now);
    $file_obj = file_load($fid_now);

    $bg_img_url = file_create_url($file_obj->uri);

    // This example is adapted from node.module.
    $block = array();

    switch ($delta) {
        case 'backgroundimage':
            $block['subject'] ="imagebackgroundblock";
            $block['content'] ="<div class='background-image'><img src='".$bg_img_url."'></div>";

            break;


    }
    return $block;
}
function backgroundimage_admin() {
    $form = array();

    $form['backgroundimage'] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#name' => 'backgroundimage_image',
        '#title' => t('upload image, huh!'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('backgroundimage', ''),
        '#description' => t("Here you can upload an image to the background!"),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#upload_location' => 'public://backgroundimage/'
    );

    return system_settings_form($form);
}
function backgroundimage_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
    dpm("yeah"); // is not being called!
    $form['backgroundimage']['#file']->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($form['backgroundimage']['#file']);
}

function backgroundimage_menu() {

    $items = array();

    $items['admin/settings/backgroundimage'] = array(
        'title' => 'Settings Background Image',
        'description' => 'Image upload',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('backgroundimage_admin'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer backgroundimage settings'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

    return $items;
}

?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have used `system_settings_form_submit()` so you can add custom submit handler for your form by adding this code to your `hook_menu`

```
function backgroundimage_admin() {
    $form = array();

    $form['backgroundimage'] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#name' => 'backgroundimage_image',
        '#title' => t('upload image, huh!'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('backgroundimage', ''),
        '#description' => t("Here you can upload an image to the background!"),
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#upload_location' => 'public://backgroundimage/'
    );
    $form['#submit'][] = 'backgroundimage_form_submit';
    return system_settings_form($form);

}
```

Comment: thanks noek, somehow the function is still not called ;(

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: the code after a return statment isnt executed ;) ...but the hint leads in the right direction! it supposed to be     $form['#submit'][] = 'backgroundimage_form_submit';
    return system_settings_form($form);

Comment: i modified your answer so that its correct!

Comment: yep , its just an example `custom _callback`

Comment: Just a quick question, how do I save the user picture avatar once I submit it from the HOOK_submit function?